# $SO_2\rightarrow GL_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Determine differentiable homomorhpisms from $SO_2$ to $GL_n$.

Are the answers the maps $t\rightarrow e^{tA}$,where $A\in M_n$ and $e^{2\pi A}=I_n$? Or is there any deeper description on $A$? Thank you

Comment: Are you familiar with the representation theory of the given group?

Comment: Yes, i know  a little @Tobias Kildetoft

Comment: Well, this question is essentially asking you to name the $n$-dimensional differentiable representations of it.

Comment: To build on Tobias' comment: Do you mean the group scheme $SO_2$ over $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{R}$ or do you mean the group of points $SO_2(\mathbb{R})$? Because if you mean the latter it may be easier (conceptually) to use the isomorphism $SO_2(\mathbb{R}) \cong \mathbb{S}^{1}$ and look for $n$-dimensional differentiable representations of the unit circle.